# Increasing legend box for a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I would like to have a legend with a text good to read (so said with a little interspace between the text), but up to now I can´t get it any bigger without loosing text of the legend (see image).
[image: barplot with legend and loosed text]

I used this programming text and par-function for the barplot and legend:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(4, 1, 3, 3), xpd = TRUE, oma = c(4, 1, 1, 1))

barplot <- barplot(data, beside=TRUE, ylim = c(0, 25),
                   cex.names = 0.8, cex.axis = 0.75, 
                   col = c("gray", "lightblue", "#0078FF", "lightgreen"))
```

preparing legend:

```
leg.txt2 <- c("position 1", "position 2", "position 3", "position 4")    
leg.col2 <- c("gray", "lightblue", "#0078FF", "lightgreen")
layout(rbind(1, 2), heights = c(7, 1))
```

setup for "no margins" on the legend

```
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), xpd = TRUE, cex = 0.8)
legend("left", leg.txt2, y.intersp=1.5, xpd=TRUE, 
       bty="n", pch=15, col=leg.col2, cex=0.8, pt.cex=0.8)
```

Does anybody know, how to increase the box of the legend?

Comment: have you tried ggplot2 - legends are so much easier.

Comment: no, I haven´t because I thougth barplot is easier... but isn´t it the same with the legend problem?

Comment: Have you tried `legend(... , horiz=TRUE)`?

Comment: yes, but I would like to have it vertical, otherwise it looks like it belongs to each of one chart...

Comment: Can you include in your post the dataset you used?

Comment: OK, how about `layout(cbind(1,2), widths = c(7,.5))`, then?